# What is User-Agent "AF_ID=<xxxxxx>"

Tags: web-crawlers

We periodically (more frequently recently) have *very agressive* crawling activity coming from EC2 instances that give us a user agent that looks like `AF_ID=<xxxxxx>`.

I've looked around for common User-Agent formats and I cannot seem to find any references to these User Agents. Do any of you know what these would be, or is it just a generic user-agent used by EC2 instances?

Comment: Do you have sofware on your server that accesses the pages internally?  Its possible to set user-agents to anything melodramatically.  Makes it possible that its a bot or software.

Answer (score 2):

It's just some random scam/spam crawler hosted on EC2.
My only advice, add this to your .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*AF_ID=* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://english-1335426938.spampoison.com/English [R=303,L] 
#http://tinyurl.com/troll-face-bot :)
```

Comment: And you're basing that "random spam" assessment on what?

Comment: On the fact that it's not an usual user agent, and agressive crawling activity. It's the usual flag to ban...

Comment: @Su' respectable bots link to their policy page in a url in the user-agent